# GarageBand drums and verse

Tags: garageband

What is the best way to add drums after I played my guitar and also what is the best effect for a verse in GarageBand

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

A guitarist needs to learn to follow a drummer so you'd be better off choosing your drum pattern and then playing along to that. Select a very simple beat at first. Not sure what you mean by "what is the best effect for a verse in GarageBand"